# Calculate Percentage Based on reverse range

Tags: math

I have a sensor that returns the reverse range. Meaning at 100% I get a value of 33 and at 0% I get a value of 116.

Normally I would use this formula

```
percentage = (value - min) / (max - min)
```

However, being that the values are reversed from the sensor how can I modify the formula to still get a percentage?

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  Can you explain how 100 becomes 33 and 0 becomes 116?

Comment: The sensor measures distance, at the furthest distance the sensor can measure I get a reading of 33v which would be 100%. On the other side when the sensor is reading no distance I get 116v which would be 0%.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2):

Considering:

- `value`: the reading from the sensor you want to convert.
- `min`: the minimum value returned from the sensor.
- `max`: the maximum value returned from the sensor.

Based on the expression you provided, the percentage can be calculated as:

```
percentage = 1 - ((value - min) / (max - min))
```

If you do some algebra, you can simplify the expression to:

```
percentage = (max - value) / (max - min)
or
percentage = (value - max) / (min - max)
```

These percentages will vary between 0 and 1 like your original expression. If you need an integer representation, you just multiply the result by 100.

Comment: The original formula returns a value between 0 and 1. Not sure why edit the answer to return a value between 0 and 100. It makes the answer inconsistent.

Comment: would min in the formula be the minimum number (33) or the minimum reading on the sensor (116)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
 P = ( ( ( value - 33 ) / ( 116 - 33 ) ) * 100 ) - 100)
```

Then i just convert it from negative to positive

Comment: This expression is almost identical to your original one. The only difference is that it returns a value between 0 and 100 instead of 0 and 1. Here 33 will give you 0, when on your original question you said it should return 100%

Comment: Yea I forgot the last part

( ( ( value - 33 ) / ( 116 - 33 ) ) * 100 ) - 100 )

Comment: a lot more contrived than: `percentage = 100 * (max - value) / (max - min)` or in your particular case `100 * (116 - value) / (116 - 33)` as suggested in my answer.